# Подскажите, задаю ссылке все те же стили что и на макете, но на макете есть еще некий внутренний отступ, и из-за этого кнопка имеет разную ширину

Tags: css

```css
.btn{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: (19.5px / 16px) * 100%;
    padding: 13px 36px 15px 36px;
    background-color: #4985FF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(111, 111, 111, 0.25);
    border-radius: 30px;
    color:#fff;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height:48px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="work__btn btn">Все услуги</div>
```

[image: На макете]

[image: У мене вышло]

Answer (score 0):

Сложно понять, потому что нет полного макета этой и других кнопок.

Например, у вас нигде не указано значение 128px, которое на скриншоте из макета. Поставьте его в min-width и уменьшите паддинги слева и справа.

Еще у вас line-height неверно задана — посмотрите в devtools значение будет перечеркнуто.

```css
.btn{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: calc(19.5 / 16);
  
  padding: 13px 36px 15px 36px;
  
  background-color: #4985FF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(111, 111, 111, 0.25);
  border-radius: 30px;
  color:#fff;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 48px;
  max-width: 200px;
  
  min-width: 128px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="work__btn btn">Все услуги</div>
```